# How do I run my application from xcode on Apple Watch?

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to run my first WatchKit application on Apple Watch (watchOS 7) from latest XCode (12.0).

I can select emulator as a destinantion, but I have no idea how to add my real watch to the list, so I can start testing on a real device.

I have iCloud account, and it seemed sufficient to run iPhone applications, but not Apple Watch.

How do I make it work?

Comment: You have to connect the phone paired with the watch to the Xcode. Make sure it appears in devices and simulators menu. Then Select the Watch App scheme in Xcode and run. Or directly run the Mobile App Destination ,Xcode will automatically install the companion watch app.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Apart from assigning a proper Team to the Project, make sure you have your iPhone (to which the Apple Watch is paired) connected to your Mac via cable.

The "connect your iPhone using cable" was not thet obvious to me. I assumed it got the device from iCloud account.